# .NET Control.Update method needed after invalidate?

Tags: .net, gdi+

In my code, just calling .Invalidate does the same thing as if an update is called.  In fact, when I call .Update afterward, the flicker for the control seems to be worse.  I read on the documentation page the following:

"The Update method just forces the control to be painted immediately"

This is confusing for me as all the online examples of redrawing tell me to specify an invalidated region, then call the update in order to get the least amount of flicker.  Based on those examples, I would assume that the update call is mandatory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This blog post describes the differences [between Control.Invalidate and Control.Update](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/subhagpo/archive/2005/02/22/378098.aspx)

> **Control.Invalidate(...)**
>
> The bool parameter denotes whether the
>   user wants to invalidate the child
>   controls of the control on which he is
>   calling Invalidate. The Rectangle
>   parameter are the bounds to invalidate
>   and the region parameter is the region
>   to invalidate. All the overloads
>   essentially end up calling one of the
>   RedrawWindow, InvaliateRect or
>   InvalidateRgn functions. If
>   RedrawWindow is called then this may
>   result in a WM_PAINT message being
>   posted to the application message
>   queue (to invalidate the child
>   controls).
>
> The important thing to note here is
>   that these functions only “invalidate”
>   or “dirty” the client area by adding
>   it to the current update region of the
>   window of the control. This
>   invalidated region, along with all
>   other areas in the update region, is
>   marked for painting when the next
>   WM_PAINT message is received. As a
>   result you may not see your control
>   refreshing (and showing the
>   invalidation) immediately (or
>   synchronously).
>
> **Control.Update()**
>
> Update function calls the UpdateWindow
>   function which updates the client area
>   of the control by sending WM_PAINT
>   message to the window (of the control)
>   if the window's update region is not
>   empty. This function sends a WM_PAINT
>   directly to WNDPROC() bypassing the
>   application message queue. Thus, if
>   the window update region is previously
>   “invalidated” then calling “update”
>   would immediately "update" (and cause
>   repaint) the invalidation.
>
> **Control.Refresh()**
>
> By now, you might have guessed what
>   Refresh( ) would be doing. Yes, it
>   calls  invalidate(true) to invalidate
>   the control and its children and then
>   calls Update( ) to force paint the
>   control so that the invalidation is
>   synchronous.

Comment: Thank you. I was googling for around 20 minutes and couldn't find a clear explanation such as this one.  I was missing the keyword 'difference'.